# how to show data from 3 combinational table using codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three database tables, *question_set*, *question* and *answer*.
*question_set* contains *set_name* and *set_id*
*question* contains *question* and also *question_set_id*
*answer* contains *answer* , *question_id*

I can not work out a way to show all the data in one view file,
I tried joins but then question data is repeating with it prints because every question has three or four answer.

Comment: A join over three tables I guess. Your question is far away from being specific. So just have this.

Comment: When you join a one-to-many relationship, yes, there will be duplicate data. And unless you can provide more specific information on what your tables look like, and the output you expect, it's probably impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought I would point out.

Your database design is horrible.

It will not scale well, and infact I do not think it would actually. work.

The way I would do it is

Three tables

`sets` => id, name
`questions` => id, set_id, question
`answers` => id, set_id, question_id, answer, points

*Note that in my above example I am taking it one step further, rather than each answer being true or false, it can have an assigned point value.
hence, an answer that you deemed half correct could be given 5 points, where as a correct answer could be given 10 points, it also works as a boolean true, just have a correct answer as 1 point, and an incorrect answer as 0 points*

Anyway.

With the above table design in mind.

You could do

```
$this->db->select('s.id as set, s.name as name, q.id as qid, q.question as qu, a.id as aid, a.answer as an, a.points as p')
         ->from('sets s')
         ->join('questions q', 'q.set_id = s.id')
         ->join('answers a', 's.set_id = s.id')
         ->where('s.id', 'SET ID');

$questions = $this->db->get();
$set = array('questions' => array());

foreach($questions as $s){
  $set['id'] = $s->set;
  $set['name'] = $s->name;
  $set['questions'][$s->qid]['id'] = $q->qid;
  $set['questions'][$s->qid]['question'] = $q->qu;
  if(!isset($set['questions'][$s->qid]['answers']))
    $set['questions'][$s->qid]['answers'] = array();
  $set['questions'][$s->qid]['answers'][] = array(
    'id' => $q->aid,
    'answer' => $q->an',
    'points' => $q->p
  );
}
```

So then you end up with an array that looks something like

```
array(
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'My first quiz',
  'questions' = array(
    array(
      'id' => 1,
      'question' => 'What is 1+1+1?',
      'answers' => array(
        array(
          'id' => 1,
          'answer' => 1,
          'points' => 0
        ),
        array(
          'id' => 2,
          'answer' => 2,
          'points' => 0
        ),
        array(
          'id' => 3,
          'answer' => 3,
          'points' => 1
        )
      )
    ),
    array(
      'id' => 2,
      'question' => 'What is 2+2+2?',
      'answers' => array(
        array(
          'id' => 4,
          'answer' => 6,
          'points' => 1
        ),
        array(
          'id' => 5,
          'answer' => 2,
          'points' => 0
        ),
        array(
          'id' => 6,
          'answer' => 3,
          'points' => 0
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Then you can do.

```
echo '<h2>'.$set['name'].'</h2>';
foreach($set['questions'] as $q){
  echo '<div class="question">';
  echo '<h3>'.$q['question'].'</h3>';
  echo '<div class="answers">';
  foreach($q['answers'] as $a){
    echo '<label for="a'.$a['id'].'">'.$a['answer'].'<input type="checkbox value="'.$a['id'].'" name="q'.$q['id'].'" /></label><br />';
  }
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, but which of course requires more SQL calls, is to use nested loops for this.

1) Join the question set and question tables
2) For each entry in the result set, retrieve the answers for that entry and put it in a separate array, nested in a bigger array where the key is the id of the question.

Your view would then look something like this:

```
foreach($questions as $question)
{
    //Print question information
    $answers = $answers_array[$question['id']];
    foreach($answers as $answer)
    {
        //Print answers information
    }
}
```

Might not be best practice but it will do the trick.

Comment: can you please show me how to do this in model and controller and i dont understand the part | For each entry in the result set, retrieve the answers for that entry and put it in a separate array, |

Comment: When you join all three tables together you will get multiple rows, one row for each answers. So for example item1 answer1, item1 answer2, item2 answer1, item3 answer1. So what I am suggesting is you create an array buy joining only the first two tables, and this array will hold the questions, in my example item1, item2, item3. Then you loop throgh these questions, or items, and for each question retrieve the answer. e.g. foreach($questions as $question) { $answers[$question['id']] = db_get_answers($question['id']); } where db_get_answers returns an array with answers. This is my suggestion.